# OpsHub Migration to VSO can't get past changeset and stops running

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I've tried this twice with the same result.

```
Error Message: OH-SCM-009 Error Occurred while sync. Could not find file 'O:\w11_10_0'
```

Version: `OpsHub Integration Manager Framework-OVSMU-V1.0.1.006`

[image: Ops hub Error]

Here are the changeset details

[image: Changeset Details]

Answer (score 0):

Close OpsHub Migration Utility.
Delete Folder w11_10_0 and Start Migration utility again.

Which will again create new folder and start syncing.

If you still getting this error, Can you please zip up and send us the log files from location :\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs and email them to ovsmu@opshub.com Please include a reference to this request in your email so we will provide proper resolution to this

Comment: I deleted all the files in the folder (The w11_10_0 file did NOT exist) and I restarted the utility.  
After a new hours, I got the same error message.  I have sent the 2nd set of logs to the email address you requested.  

Is there a way to simply skip a changeset?

I will also note that my VSO project now contains a DUPLICATE set of changesets!

Comment: Hello.  I've submitted the requested information to the email specified.  Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

At one point if you moved code from one TFS Team Project to a New Team Project and DELETED the original team project then this may cause this issue.